# Python Firebase Admin listener automatically fires every hour

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I noticed my Firebase admin event listener was getting triggered every hour, even when there were no changes in my database. I put together a small test program to verify, and am seeing that these updates are automatically happening each hour, ~60min after the initial listener is set up.

Is this intentional? And if so, how can I disable this behavior?

Here is the test program (I've removed a few *SENSITIVE VALUES*):

```
# Firebase modules
import os
import datetime
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import credentials

# Init Firebase.
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
cred = credentials.Certificate(dir_path + '/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': *DB_URL*
})


def db(event):
    print('Firebase event detected: ')
    print('Path: ' + event.path)
    print('Data: ' + event.data)
    print('Event type: ' + event.event_type)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    human_timestamp = '{y}-{mon}-{d} {h}:{min}:{s}'.format(
        y=now.year,
        mon=now.month,
        d=now.day,
        h=now.hour,
        min=now.minute,
        s=now.second
    )

    print(human_timestamp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loc_path = *LOC_PATH*
    listener = firebase_admin.db.reference(loc_path).listen(db)

    try: 
        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        listener.close()
```

I ran this for an hour, and saw the following output:

```
Firebase event detected: 
Path: /
Data: test
Type: put
2019-2-3 9:11:58
Firebase event detected: 
Path: /
Data: test
Type: put
2019-2-3 10:12:4
```

Comment: This is a big problem because has increased the download volume and, hence, my firebase bill. I've submitted this problem to firebase, please consider doing the same so that they fix it.

Comment: See the response here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/267

Comment: Thanks. Saw it and responded there. Downloading the entire database every hour is not an option. Firebase is not free and downloading all this data unnecessarily every hour has a real cost. Their response in not acceptable. We should push for a real solution. We are paying for this service; this is not charity.